# HTTP Request to a VirtualHost

Tags: paw-app

Here's the thing, I have my server configured with a virtualhost `mydomain.com` but the DNS are not pointing yet to this server's IP address.

In other words, I have:

- `mydomain.com` DNS pointing to server A
- a server B with a `mydomain.com` virtualhost

I need to connect to server B pretending I'm connecting to `mydomain.com`.

Is it possible to test that with Paw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is probably DNS spoofing, you need to connect to your "server B"'s IP address but with an HTTP header `Host: mydomain.com`.

See [DNS Spoofing with Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/DNS_Spoofing).

Comment: Thanks Micha. I add the Host header and use the IP in the URL input and it works.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to figure it out, so here's a screenshot that may explain the solution better.

I'm trying to access the virtualhost `mydomain.com` on the server with IP address `0.0.0.0`.

[image: Paw VirtualHost]